# javascript append colon to variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript function in which am trying to send some data to another php script. I have to send an array of values to the php script. I am trying to append : to each value in the javascript function so that I can use implode to get the array values in my php script. This is the javascript function I have.

```
$("#update-form").submit(function(e) {
$passdata = "";
    <?php
    for ($i=1; $i <= $total_columns - 1 ; $i++) { 

        printf('$passdata+=$("#slider%d").val().:;' . PHP_EOL, $i);
    }
    ?> 
      if ($(this).is(':not([data-submit="true"])'))
      {
        $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="'+$passdata+'">');
        $('form').data('submit', 'true').submit();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
     }
     })
```

I used  `printf('$passdata+=$("#slider%d").val().:;' . PHP_EOL, $i);` However, I am not able to see the variable in php script. I also tried,

```
printf('$passdata+=$("#slider%d").val()+=:;' . PHP_EOL, $i);
```

How can I append **:** to the variable in my javascript function?

Comment: Look at the generated source as it appears in your browser. Does it look right to you?

Comment: Did you bother checking if `$total_columns` actually exists and that your for() loop is actually running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what it generates in the client, is that valid JavaScript?

```
$passdata+=$("#slider1").val().:;
```

JavaScript does not do string concatenation that way.

```
$passdata+=$("#slider1").val() + ":";
```

If I were you, I would use an array and join()

```
 $passdata.push($("#slider1").val());
```

and than make it a string

```
var myValue = $passdata.join(":");
```

Even better, do not use PHP to generate the JavaScript! Just add a class on the elements and use a single selector with map();

```
$(".myCommonClass").map( function(){ return this.value; }).get().join(":");
```

Or just post multiple form element names to the server and handle the multiple values on the server like forms always work.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than hacking around this abomination, why not just do something like this:

Add a class to all of your sliders. Then:

```
$(".sliderClassNameHere").map(function(x) {return x.value;}).get().join(":");
```

Alternatively... just submit the sliders...?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use json? In PHP you use json_encode(), put it in hidden input's value, and then in javascript you use function json_decode() on that value. That's what json is for.